# How to do get data out of multiple `countof`s on single table in SQLite?

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

I have a table with data and having a column with a date value and an affinity column, which can have 5 different values (i.e. `a`,`b`,`c`,`d`,`e`).

```
Table A
table_id     date    affinity
```

I need to count how many entries there is per `month of the year` per `affinity`. I initially created an sql query for each month per affinity, so the database gets opened for about 60 times, which is too much for most android phones to handle and is super slow.

How I can condense this in a single query and then how I can get the values? Ideally I would create a temporary table that looks like this with sample values.

```
    Jan    Feb    Mar    Apr    May ...
a   2      4      6      4      1
b   4      1      3      4      0
c   2      2      4      2      0
d   7      3      6      0      5
e   9      5      1      9      8
```

I am not well versed with advanced sql querying, but I do know of JOINS and nested SELECTS. So I just need a little push in the right direction. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to do this by using a `case` expression in conjunction with the `count` function:

```
select 
    affinity
    , count(case when month(`date`) = 1 then affinity end) as "Jan"
    , count(case when month(`date`) = 2 then affinity end) as "Feb"
    , count(case when month(`date`) = 3 then affinity end) as "Mar"
    , count(case when month(`date`) = 4 then affinity end) as "Apr"
    , count(case when month(`date`) = 5 then affinity end) as "May"
    -- ... etc.
from a -- this is your table, which I assumed is called 'a'
group by affinity;
```

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6a92c/1)

As SQLite doesn't have any `month` function, you would have to use the `strftime` function instead: `strftime('%m', date)`

For SQLite the query should probably look lie this:

```
select 
    affinity
    , count(case when strftime('%m', date) = '01' then affinity end) as "Jan"
    , count(case when strftime('%m', date) = '02' then affinity end) as "Feb"
    , count(case when strftime('%m', date) = '03' then affinity end) as "Mar"
    , count(case when strftime('%m', date) = '04' then affinity end) as "Apr"
    , count(case when strftime('%m', date) = '05' then affinity end) as "May"
from a -- this is your table, which I assumed is called 'a'
group by affinity;
```

Comment: Wow let me try this. Are these keywords present in SQLite?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe SQLite uses a slightly different syntax as there is no month function. I've updated the answer to include that.

Comment: Thanks a lot, let me try it out.

Comment: I hope you're online, the 'from a' the 'a' here is a value of affinity? Or is it a keyword? WIill it cover for all the values of affinity?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe No, `a` in the context `from a` would be your table, which I assumed was named `a`. Maybe it is called `TableA`? Your question is a bit ambiguous in that regard.

Comment: Thank you very much for the inputs. I really can't disclose all of the details I'm really sorry. But please know I appreciate all of your inputs thank you very much

Comment: Thank you this really worked perfectly! But I have a question, why does it create 13 columns instead of just 12?

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe It creates one column for `affinity` and 12 columns for the months.

Comment: Okay makes sense. Thank you!

Comment: Hello, how do I make it so that it always returns 5 rows even if there is only one entry in the table? Also, I'm facing a problem that when I that one entry's affinity is c, it gets on the row with affinity a because it is the only entry on the table (^^; ) help please

Comment: @JohnErnestGuadalupe If you always want 5 rows (I assume you want Affinity A-F) you have to construct a set that has the 5 values and then use a left join with your table. You can do this with a derived table and union queries. Look at this SQL Fiddle for an example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a0e3f/2 Note that you have to change the month function to the one used with SQLite.

Answer (score 1):

Investigate 'GROUP BY' and its aggregate functions. Something like:

```
SELECT COUNT() AS C, affinity, date 
FROM ...
GROUP BY affinity, date
```

Gives you the list of records. Reorder to matrix if necessary.